# Monitor terminal commands / Override script

Tags: ruby, git, bash, terminal

I want implement one thing, but i'm really newbie in scripting.

When I run some script (`carthage update` in my case) via terminal from project directory I want to check current **git-branch**:

1. If it's a **develop** branch - run terminal script.
2. Something else - show error, that this script can be runned only from **develop** brunch.

Hope someone can point out me a correct direction.

Comment: Are you just asking how to get the current git branch?  What language do you want that in?

Answer (score 0):

First, find out what the current branch name is, then, use it in an "if" statement.  Adjust the script to your specific needs.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

git_branch=$(git status); 
git_branch=$(echo ${git_branch} | awk ' { print $3 } '); 

if [[ "${git_branch}" == 'master' ]]; then 
    echo ${git_branch};
else
    echo "Error: ... "
    return 1
fi; 

echo "Script finished."
```